# Perl uninitialized value in numeric code

Tags: perl, hashmap, initialization

I get these errors when i run this code I get these warnings that I really do not understand. When i change the == to a = i still get an error. :

```
Use of uninitialized value in numeric eq (==) at ./pennies_again line 53, <$ogen_fh> line 2336
Use of uninitialized value in numeric eq (==) at ./pennies_again line 53, <$ogen_fh> line 2336.
Use of uninitialized value in numeric eq (==) at ./pennies_again line 53, <$ogen_fh> line 2336.
Use of uninitialized value in numeric eq (==) at ./pennies_again line 53, <$ogen_fh> line 2336.
Use of uninitialized value in numeric eq (==) at ./pennies_again line 53, <$ogen_fh> line 2336.
Use of uninitialized value in numeric eq (==) at ./pennies_again line 53, <$ogen_fh> line 2336.
Use of uninitialized value in numeric eq (==) at ./pennies_again line 53, <$ogen_fh> line 2336.
Use of uninitialized value in numeric eq (==) at ./pennies_again line 53, <$ogen_fh> line 2336.
Use of uninitialized value in numeric eq (==) at ./pennies_again line 53, <$ogen_fh> line 2336.

A
AA
AAL
AAPL
ABT
ABT
SPIN
ABX
```

this is line 2336 on the cat- does not seem like much  - I skipped the line  - I think it is line 53 that I am really concerned with.

```
$ cat -n /imp/data/config/foo.cfg | tail
2327          AOSAskEdge = rAOSAskEdge
2328          AOSBidEdge = rAOSBidEdge
2329  }
2330
2331
2332  SvcSwap = {
2333      VCE = TVGEN
2334  }
2335  }
2336  # vi:set cindent,cino=+0
```

This is the code, it is the part where the symbol hash is symbol_hash{$1} == 1. I do not even know what this means :

```
#!/sbc/perl/bin/perl
#/sbcimp/etds_extend.pl
use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;
use Data::Dumper;
my $dbUser = '1';
my $dbPass = '_01';
my $dbSid  = 'A.WORLD';
my $dbh    = DBI->connect( "dbi:Oracle:$dbSid", "$dbUser", "$dbPass" ) or die("Couldn't connect: $!");

#sub read_extend

my %symbol_hash = ();
my $query       = "select e_risk_symbol from gsd_etds where level_name='CS' order by e_risk_symbol";
if ( !$dbh ) {
    print "Error connecting to DataBase; $DBI::errstr\n";
}
my $cur_msg = $dbh->prepare($query) or die "\n\nCould not prepare statement: " . $dbh->errstr;
$cur_msg->execute();
while ( my @row = $cur_msg->fetchrow_array ) {
    $symbol_hash{ $row[0] } = 1;
}
#for my $symbol (sort keys %symbol_hash ) {
#    print "$symbol\n" ;
#
#}

my %extend_hash   = ();
my @error_array   = ();
my %penny_hash    = ();
my $penny_file    = "/sbcig/qgen.cfg";
my $ticksize_flag = 0;
my $penny_flag    = 0;
my $member_flag   = 0;
open( my $ogen_fh, '<', "$penny_file" ) or die "Can't open $penny_file for reading: $!";

foreach my $line (<$ogen_fh>) {
    next if ( $line =~ m/vi:set cindent,cino=+0/ );

    chomp($line);
    if ( $line =~ /^\s*TickSize\s+=\s+\{/ ) {
        $ticksize_flag = 1;
    }
    elsif ( ( $ticksize_flag == 1 ) && ( $line =~ /^\s*penny.*\s+=\s+\{/ ) ) {
        $penny_flag = 1;
    }
    elsif ( ( $penny_flag == 1 ) && ( $line =~ /^\s*members\s+=\s+\{/ ) ) {
        $member_flag = 1;
    }
    elsif ( ( $member_flag == 1 ) && ( $line =~ /\}/ ) ) {
        $member_flag = 0;
    }
    elsif ( ( $member_flag == 1 ) && ( $line =~ /\s*(\S+)\s*$/ ) ) {
        if ( $symbol_hash{$1} == 1 ) {                       ### Line 53
            $penny_hash{$1} = 1;
        }
    }
    elsif ( ( $penny_flag == 1 ) && ( $line =~ /\}/ ) ) {
        $penny_flag = 0;
    }
    elsif ( ( $ticksize_flag == 1 ) && ( $line =~ /\}/ ) ) {
        $ticksize_flag = 0;
    }
}

for my $penny ( sort keys %penny_hash ) {
    print "$penny\n";
    sleep 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values of every element of `%symbol_hash` is `1`, so the two values you can get from `$symbol_hash{EXPR}` are `1` and undefined (for non-existent elements). The later warns when compared using `==`.

You're checking if the hash element exists, so you could use

```
if (exists($symbol_hash{$1}))
```

instead of

```
if ($symbol_hash{$1} == 1)
```

But since all the values that exist are true and those that don't are false, all that's required is

```
if ($symbol_hash{$1})
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `%symbol_hash` is not always initialized for keys you're trying to access:

```
    if ( $symbol_hash{$1} == 1 ) {                       ### Line 53
```

One fix is to verify that the key exists before using it in a numerical comparison `==`:

```
    if ( $symbol_hash{$1} && $symbol_hash{$1} == 1 ) {
```

However, given the context of how the hash is initialized, the only possible values are `1` or [`undef`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/undef.html).

Therefore, all you actually want to test for is a true value:

```
    if ( $symbol_hash{$1} ) {
```

Comment: True.  Given the context of how the hash is initialized, the only possible values are `1` or [`undef`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/undef.html).  I had not attempted to decipher the earlier part of the script yet.